# Python - Datetime format with underscore

Tags: python, datetime

I've declared date as a string like this,

```
from_date = '2018_04_01'
```

and converted it into datetime format,

```
from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(from_date), "%Y_%m_%d")
```

the from date now is formatted as,

```
2018-04-01
```

I want the from date with underscore, and in datetime format.

strftime would return the required format but in string. This could be again formatted to a datetime format - this is the worst possible and cumbersome way to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's not possible without subclassing `datetime` or ugly hacks like overwriting `datetime.__str__`.

Comment: I need an "_" in my datetime, that is how it is.

Comment: Then use `strftime("%Y_%m_%d")` when you need it. Why do you have to change the `__str__` behavior?

Comment: @Aran-Fey beat me by the seconds!

Comment: @Aran-Fey strftime returns in string. I am tring to get my from_date with an _ and in datetime format.

Comment: `2018-04-01` is also a string. The output you want is a string. When you ask for a _formatted_ date, you're asking for a string. _Whenever you need the datetime formatted as `%Y_%m_%d`, use `strftime`._

Comment: @Zedaiq You are confusing the internal representation of a date with its string representation. Internally, the date is most likely an integer. Only when you call a function like `strftime` does it get converted to a string. And only when it gets converted to string does `_` or `-` come into play.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

you can do this

```
from_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2018_04_01", "%Y_%m_%d").strftime("%Y_%m_%d")
```

Comment: Trying to parse that string with the format `"%Y-%m-%d"` will throw an error.

Comment: It's an improvement because it doesn't throw an error, but now it's a no-op. You might as well do `from_date = from_date` or `pass` or nothing.

Answer (score 9):

You mean something like this ?

```
from datetime import datetime, date

print "{:%Y_%m_%d}".format(datetime.now())
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert datetime object (date+time) in underscore:

```
from datetime import datetime
str(datetime.now())
"{:%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S}".format(datetime.now())
```

%H: Returns the hour. In our example, it returned "00".
%M: Returns the minute, from 00 to 59. In our example, it returned "00".
%S: Returns the second, from 00 to 59. In our example, it returned "00".